# Can I check which Double Twin cards I've found?

Tags: evoland

Is there a way to look at the cards/stars that have been collected already?

I know that guy in town will tell you where one of the cards and stars yet to be found are hidden, but I would like to know which cards I've already collected.  I could keep having duels but that seems random and unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to view your cards in game.

The only way you can check your cards is by playing the Double Twin card game and making a note of the random cards that appear.